# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to import data from a json file and render a list of images. But I get an error saying: **Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

This is the file which seems to generate the error:

```
import React from 'react';
import Product from "./Product/index";

const ProductList = () => {
    const renderedList = import("../../../data/data.json").then(json 
    => json.goods.map(image => {
        return <div><Product images={image.pictures} /></div>
    }
));

    return <div>{renderedList}</div>
}

export default ProductList;
```

This is my data.json file:

```
{
"goods": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Cat Tee Black T-Shirt",
        "prices": "$ 10.90",
        "pictures": "120642730401995392_1.jpg",
        "size": "",
        "quantity": ""    
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Dark Thug Blue-Navy T-Shirt",
        "prices": "$ 29.45",
        "pictures": "51498472915966370_1.jpg",
        "size": "",
        "quantity": ""    
    }]
}
```

This is my Product component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Thumb from "../../../Thumb/index";

const Product = props => {
        return (
            <div className="shelf-item">
                <div className="shelf-stopper">Free shipping</div>
                <Thumb 
                    classes="shelf-item__thumb"
                    src={props.images}
                />
                <p className="shelf-item__title">product</p>
                <div className="shelf-item__price">
                    productInstallment  
                </div>
                <div className="shelf-item__buy-btn">Add to cart</div>
            </div>
        );
    }

export default Product;
```

Could someone help me figure it out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you show us your Project component?

Comment: Do you mean the `Product` component? Sure, I have added it.

Comment: Oh yeah! Sorry my bad. Looking at the code, there shouldn't be an error with rendering imo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your productList component you are using a promise instead of rendering child, to overcome this you can make it a stateful component fix this like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Product from "./Product/index";

class ProductList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      goods: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    import("../../../data/data.json")
      .then(json => this.state({ goods: json.goods }))
  }

  render() {
    const { goods } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        {goods.map(image => <div><Product images={image.pictures} /></div>)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ProductList;
```

or alternatively you can import it in beginning like:

```
import React from 'react';
import Product from "./Product/index";
import goods from "../../../data/data.json"

const ProductList = () => {
  const renderedGoods = goods.map(image => {
    return <div><Product images={image.pictures} /></div>
  })
  return <div>{renderedGoods}</div>
}

export default ProductList;
```

Not an issue, yes you resolved the promise correct,

but as even when you type in console what you are actually returning is a promise and .then or .catch are callbacks called when its either resolved or rejected so you see react wants is something to render and you cannot render a promise

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I am still a little confused that what did **you are using a promise instead of rendering child** mean? I did use a promise, but I also resolved it and returned the JSX component. I am a newbie to react, sorry for this question if it is so stupid : P

Comment: I have updated the answer with the explanation below as well, its just .then and .catch are callbacks called after the promise and react wants something to render and you cannot render a promise

Comment: Wow, I got it lol! Thanks so much for your extra explanation!

Comment: glad could explain it properly

Answer (score 2):

It works but why you are importing json data use axios insted of import.
[Axios documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Your component will look like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Product from "./Product/index";

class ProductList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      products: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    axios.get("products.json").then(json => {
        this.setState({ products: json.data.goods });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { products } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        {products.map(image => <div><Product images={image.pictures} /></div>)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ProductList;
```

**Keep your json or data file inside public folder**

I hope this works for you

Answer (score 2):

Just use `map` or filter function as the `Array` you are trying to render is an array of Objects and those Objects can't be rendered due to multiple re-rendering and hence React DOM won't allow that .

Answer (score 1):

Close - move the import to the top of file:

```
import myData from "../../../data/data.json";
```

Then change your rendered list to this:

```
const renderedList = myData.goods.map(image => (<div><Product images={image.pictures} /></div>));
```