# Resolving "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])" in Functional Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios

I have the following in a functional component.

```js
const [trucks, setTrucks] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
    Request.getTrucksForToday().then((x) => {setTrucks(x)}); // <-- this is an async function to an axios request
});

return (
...

{trucks.map((truck) =>{return<LocalShippingIcon lat={truck.latitude} lng={truck.longitude} text={truck.name}/>})}
...
);
```

All of the solutions I have seen for this problem suggest just putting the async function in `componentDidMount()` ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47659112/10973706), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54229255/10973706)). Is there a way to solve it without doing this?

for completeness here is the function

```js
export function getTrucksForToday() {
  return axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: constants.backend_url + "schedule/getTrucksForToday",
    headers: request_headers
  })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
      return error;
    });
}
```

Comment: can u ckeck.. `Request.getTrucksForToday().` i think it wriiten wrong , async function again returning asyn. add code of Request.getTrucksForToday() function

Comment: what is the rest of the returned code for that component, the problem might be elsewhere

Comment: yeah!! i think issue in LocalShippingIcon component.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli @xdeepakv its a rather large component and these are the only locations where `trucks` is used. But a link to the repo is https://github.com/MarkFuller1/Food-Truck-Finder/blob/fixPromises/src/js/components/Dashboard.js

Comment: My component was declared as async, problem solved, thank you for your efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `[]` to useEffect()

```
const [trucks, setTrucks] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
    Request.getTrucksForToday().then((x) => {setTrucks(x)}); // <-- this is an async function to an axios request
},[]);

return (
...

{trucks.map((truck) =>{return<LocalShippingIcon lat={truck.latitude} lng={truck.longitude} text={truck.name}/>})}
...
);
```

Comment: can you do a console.log(truck) inside map and post the value

Comment: its `[]`because the request is never made. Its using the value in `useState`